# How can I move the video on the side?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>
    Home - Hasan's Website
  </title>
  <style>
    .courseinfo{
    margin:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }

    .jumbotron {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-image: url(image.jpg);
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }

    .navigation {
      background-color: #330;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    }

    .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
    }

    .navigation a:hover {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .navigation a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    .intro {
      background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }

    .secondbg {
      background-image: url("circuit.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: top;
    }

    .barofcolour {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      padding: 1%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;

    }

    .coursep {
      width:40%;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      margin-left: 1%



    }

    .whatwelearn{
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    width:60%;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin:1%;
    }

    .listoflearn {
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin:1%;
    }

    .backoftable {
    background-color: burlywood;
    width:40%;
    height:45%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 0.05%;
    padding-bottom: 0.05%;
}

    .learningpic{
    float:right;
    align-content: center;
    margin-top: 11%;
    }

    .engvideo{
      float: right;
      top: 50%;
    }



  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
    <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
  </div>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="secondbg">
      <div class = "barofcolour">
          <div class="courseinfo">
            <h2>About This Course</h2>
          </div>
      </div>

       <div class="coursep">
        <p>This course examines computer systems and control of external devices. Students will develop
          knowledge and skills in electronics, interfacing, programming, and networks, will build systems that
          use computer programs and interfaces to control and respond to external devices. Students will
          develop an awareness of related environmental and societal issues, and will learn about college and
          university programs leading to careers in computer technology.</p>
      </div>


     <div class = "backoftable">
          <div class = "learningpic">
            <img src="Psychology.jpg" alt="Learning" width="303" height="303">
          </div>
        <div class = "whatwelearn">
          <h2>What We Learn:</h2>
        <div class = "listoflearn">
            <ul>
                <li>Web Development</li>
                <li>Basic Electronics</li>
                <li>Programming</li>
                <li>Digital Electronics</li>
                <li>Interfacing</li>
                <li>Technology Environment Careers Safety Society</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "engvideo">
            <video src="compeng video.mp4"  type="audio/mpeg" height="450" width="800"/>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>






</body>

</html>
```

Hi, I have two problems. My first problem is that I can get my video to be on the same altitude as my "What We Learn" box. I want the video to be on the same level as that, but on the right side of the screen. Also, how do I play my video? It is just all white? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. This is for my assignment at school.

Here is an example of what I want: https://gyazo.com/91f34068246795003503d6294a1a045b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.courseinfo {
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.jumbotron {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-position: 0% 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #330;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
}

.navigation a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: black;
}

.navigation a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.intro {
  background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 4;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.secondbg {
  background-image: url("circuit.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: top;
}

.barofcolour {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-position: 0% 25%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px;
}

.coursep {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-left: 1%
}

.whatwelearn {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 1%;
}

.listoflearn {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 1%;
}

.backoftable {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 0.05%;
  padding-bottom: 0.05%;
}

.learning {
    display: flex;
    background-color: burlywood;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
      width: 60%;
}

.engvideo {
  width: 40%
}

.engvideo video{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
  <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
  <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
</div>
<div class="intro">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="secondbg">
  <div class="barofcolour">
    <div class="courseinfo">
      <h2>About This Course</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="coursep">
    <p>This course examines computer systems and control of external devices. Students will develop knowledge and skills in electronics, interfacing, programming, and networks, will build systems that use computer programs and interfaces to control and respond
      to external devices. Students will develop an awareness of related environmental and societal issues, and will learn about college and university programs leading to careers in computer technology.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="backoftable">
    <div class="learning">
      <div class="whatwelearn">
        <h2>What We Learn:</h2>
        <div class="listoflearn">
          <ul>
            <li>Web Development</li>
            <li>Basic Electronics</li>
            <li>Programming</li>
            <li>Digital Electronics</li>
            <li>Interfacing</li>
            <li>Technology Environment Careers Safety Society</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="learningpic">
      <img src="Psychology.jpg" alt="Learning" width="303" height="303">
    </div>
     </div>
    <div class="engvideo">
      <video controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but that just made the colour bar span across the screen. I dont wan't the video on the colour.

Comment: Sorry, it did the same thing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nice work! We are very close. We just need to remove the brown colour between the video and the brain? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: i cannot see any brown color. can you please send me screen shot.. and also if possible add that brain image

Comment: Here is the screenshot: https://gyazo.com/cd634da6e27c3d0ef7cb123f442ceeb1. The brain is the colorful one here: https://oupeltglobalblog.com/2018/03/27/psychology-language-learning/

Comment: if you're giving `width` in percent then the width will increase right??.. currently your left section has 60% and right has 40%.. so it will take 60% according to the size of the screen

Comment: When I reduce the width of the .learning class, the bar of colour gets smaller which is a good thing, but it takes the video with it. https://gyazo.com/acd5cb6de3fa042ed5f1fe2c21313f42 I really want the video on the right side of the background, not touching other elements.

Comment: increase the width of `.engvideo` class

Comment: Putting justify-content: space-between; did not change anything :(